# Adjust oom_score at process launch

Tags: linux, oom, oom-killer

I've got a few servers that have begun oom-killing their backup processes and, while I understand that encountering the oom condition is quite bad in itself, I need this process to *not* die so that backups happen properly while the memory issue is addressed.

To that end I've attempted to create way to launch processes with adjusted oom_scores in a way similar to launching a process with `nice`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function oom_adj_exec() {
    while getopts ':n:' opt; do
        case $opt in
            n)
                if grep -q '^-\?[0-9]\+$' <(echo "$OPTARG"); then
                    if [ "$OPTARG" -ge -1000 -a "$OPTARG" -le 1000 ]; then
                        oom_score_adjust=$OPTARG
                    else
                        echo "Acceptable values for -n are from -1000 to 1000" >&2
                        return 255
                    fi
                else
                    echo "Improper format for -n: $OPTARG" >&2
                    return 255
                fi
                break
                ;;
            :)
                echo "option -$OPTARG requires a value" >&2
                return 255
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Unknown option -$opt" >&2
                return 255
                ;;
        esac
    done

    command=${@:$OPTIND}

    # job control requires the monitor option which
    # is usually not set for non-interactive shells
    prev_state=$(set +o | grep monitor)
    set -o monitor

    $command &
    pid=$!

    echo "$oom_score_adjust" > /proc/$pid/oom_score_adj

    fg %% > /dev/null

    ecode=$?

    # restore the previous state of the shell
    $prev_state

    return $ecode
}

oom_adj_exec $@
```

Example usage:

```
./oom_adj_exec.sh -n -500 /usr/bin/mem_bloater
```

While it seems to work I can't shake the feeling like there's something waiting in there to go horribly wrong. Is there anything that stands out as being a truly terrible idea and/or disaster waiting to happen?

Comment: The acceptable values for [`oom_score_adj`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) range from -1000 to +1000 so you might replace the test `grep -q '^-\?[0-9]\+$' <(echo "$OPTARG")` with `[ "$OPTARG" -ge -1000 -a "$OPTARG" -le 1000 ]` but otherwise nothing immediately makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: This is true, but I also want to explicitly test for non-digit characters so I've added this as an additional check. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC `-ge` and `-le` will already trow a failure when used to test non-integers so 2 birds with one stone...

Comment: True, but not gracefully. I'm a stickler. :P

Answer (score 3):

I've also done this but not quite as nicely, like so:

```
(echo 1000 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj && exec /usr/bin/blah)
```

Because it's in parentheses, it launches a subshell, sets the OOM score for the shell (in this case to 1000, to make it extremely likely to get killed in an OOM situation), and then the `exec` replaces the subshell with the intended program while leaving the new OOM score intact.  It also won't affect the OOM score of the parent process/shell, as everything is happening inside the subshell.